# set selected page number - kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, kendo-grid

I am creating a grid using kendo-telrik. In this suppose I am having 100 data. From this in json I have only 10 data(suppose first page contains 10 data in pagination). And I am showing all pages(10 pages for 100 data) all the time.

When I click on another page then get next 10 data and show it in ui. For this I am using page change function of kendo grid and get next 10 data.Now I want to list that data in grid with page which I selected.

For this I create sample which is as - http://jsfiddle.net/pporwal26/y6KdK/76/

```
 var jsonData = JSON.parse("{\"Report\":\"type1\",\"FileList\":[{\"owner\":\"machine-174\\\\admin\",\"path\":\"C:\\\\workarea\\\\WinTest1lakhfileinKB\\\\WinTest\\\\nGYh\\\\SMv\\\\U1P8FLx\\\\vMbhdo\\\\TgFSW\\\\42Ioulj0w.txt\"},{\"owner\":\"machine-174admin\",\"path\":\"C:\\\\workarea\\\\bada_data\\\\Employee Database - Copy (7) - Copy.mdb\"}],\"Count\":100,\"total\":100,\"page\":1}");
function nextData(page){
jsonData = JSON.parse("{\"Report\":\"type1\",\"FileList\":[{\"owner\":\"machine-170\\\\admin\",\"path\":\"C:\\\\workarea\\\\WinTest1lakhfileinKB\\\\WinTest\\\\nGYh\\\\SMv\\\\U1P8FLx\"},{\"owner\":\"machine-170admin\",\"path\":\"C:\\\\workarea\"}],\"Count\":100,\"total\":100,\"page\":"+page+"}");
createGrid(jsonData);
}
createGrid(jsonData);
function createGrid(jsonData){
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
   pageable: true,
   scrollable: true,
   page: jsonData.page,
   pageable: {
         pageSize: 2,
         refresh: true,
         change:function(e){
           nextData(e.index);
         }
     },
   dataSource: {
       serverPaging: true,
       schema: {
           data: "FileList",
           total: "total"

       },
       data: jsonData 
   }
});
}
```

In this sample when I click on change event than it always show 1 page not the page which I selected. and also want that on each click grid is always create new not add in it. What can I do for that?

Answer (score 0):

Well I know that calling `createGrid(jsonData);` inside of the `nextData` function, you're going to create a table for every time you increment, that alone will cause bugs. Have you tried commenting that out?

I've personally never used kendoGrid, so if my answer's no good, I do apologies, but from having had a look online, this seems to work?

Worst case, you do need that change, in which case, can't you target the data inside the table and just over ride it in some other function? A pretty morbid way of doing it would be to delete/destroy the current one in order to make a new one. But it would work I guess?

Comment: Thanks for reply.But I want that grid contains new data when page change and my restriction is I had only page size data and get next page data on next page click.So I how I create grid with new data i I am not call creategrid(jsondata) from nextdata().

Comment: I did try to create a function called updateData, inside I just did: $("#grid").kendoGrid({ data: jsonData }); But that also seems to create a new grid inside.... My only suggestion could be to find a way to ONLY create a new datasource? - This seems kidna useful? :- [Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing)